# Using new format string specifier configuration dictionary (plurals support) in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, localization, internationalization

I'm trying to use the new support for more sophisticated localization of plurals in iOS 7. I've created a .stringsdict file, formatted according to the information in the Foundation release notes (and What's New In Cocoa WWDC session). I've verified that the .stringsdict is being copied into my app's bundle (and indeed `-[NSBundle pathForResource:...]` finds it). However, `+[NSString localizedStringWithFormat:]` doesn't return a string formatted according to the rules in the configuration dictionary.

Code:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldEditingDidEnd:(UITextField *)sender
{
    NSInteger numPeople = [sender.text integerValue];
    self.textView.text = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:
                          NSLocalizedString(@"%d people are in the room", @"%d people are in the room"), (long)numPeople];
}
```

Localizable.stringsdict:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
     <key>%d people are in the room</key>
     <dict>
          <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
          <string>%#@num_people_in_room@ in the room</string>
          <key>num_people_in_room</key>
          <dict>
               <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
               <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
                     <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
                     <string>d</string>
               <key>zero</key>
               <string>No one is</string>
                     <key>one</key>
                     <string>A person is</string>
               <key>two</key>
               <string>Two people are</string>
                     <key>other</key>
                     <string>%d people are</string>
          </dict>
     </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've also uploaded a complete, very simple sample project here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mfze377g0r1iqde/PluralDemo.zip . You enter a number in the text field, and a label is updated with the result of `-localizedStringWithFormat:`.

Has anyone gotten this to work? Have I done something wrong in setting it up?

Comment: Did you try this APi StringWithFormat:??

Comment: It seems to me that this is a feature of Cocoa (OS X) only, but not available in Cocoa Touch (iOS).

Comment: @hussainShabbir, yes, I've tried that with no change in behavior. The referenced WWDC session is clear that `-localizedStringWithFormat:` is the correct method (as it was for this kind of thing even before this new, better plurals support).

Comment: @MartinR, you might be right! I can't actually find any reference to this stuff in iOS 7 docs. However, I actually tried on 10.9 first (I'm really an OS X developer), and have the exact same problem. I only asked about iOS 7 because of the NDA...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

stringsdict (plurals) works in both OS X Mavericks and iOS 7 and is based on Unicode CLDR (Common Locale Data Repository). English supports only zero, one, and other. "Two" is supported in some languages, such as Arabic, Hebrew, Irish, etc.

#### Sources:

- [Foundation Release Notes for OS X v10.9](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html)
- [Unicode CLDR Language Plural Rules](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html)

#### Update (Sep 1, 2015):

As I mentioned in a response below (from Jan 13, 2014), the regular strings file is still required, even if it's empty.

> did you also add an empty strings file? The documentation says that you must add the strings file even if it's going to be empty, probably due to the internal implementation of localization in Cocoa.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @bolot. Unfortunately, this still doesn't work for me. Since this question was posted, I've tried specifying formats for only 'one' and 'other'. In both cases (ie. variable is 1 and variable is >1), the formatted string is not changed to reflect the pluralization rules in the stringsdict file. I've tried this on both OS X and iOS 7.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen did you also add an empty strings file? The documentation says that you must add the strings file even if it's going to be empty, probably due to the internal implementation of localization in Cocoa.

Comment: Thank you, nice catch! I think that note was added to the documentation after I asked this question. That fixes the problem, and this is working fine now.

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is that you are missing `Localizable.strings` file.

*It is required even if it is empty*.

Tried it with your project and adding the file made the project work just fine.

Comment: Thanks! Spent ages trying to figure out why it wasn't working!