# Pluralized dictionary always return the value from "zero" key

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocalizedstring

I'm using the new stringsdict format to localize and pluralize some strings in my app.

I read [this](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html) and [this](http://www.objc.io/issue-9/string-localization.html) for reference and I hope my localized strings from stringsdict is grabbed correctly.

The problem is, I see the value from "zero" key always and I don't know what's wrong is happening here, because is very difficult to debug the operations inside localization methods.

Let me put some code here:

1 - This is my Localizable.stringsdict file, also exist a Localizable.strings in same project.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>%i minutes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
            <string>%i %#@minutes@</string>
            <key>minutes</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
                <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
                <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
                <string>i</string>
                <key>one</key>
                <string>One minute</string>
                <key>two</key>
                <string>Two minutes</string>
                <key>other</key>
                <string>Other minutes</string>
                <key>zero</key>
                <string>Zero minutes</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

2 - There is a simple code to test this string

```
NSString *output = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%i minutes", nil), 5 ];
NSLog(@"Output: %@", output); // And here, always display "Output: 5 Zero minutes" independently the value I put in the formated string, in this case (five) needs to display "Output: 5 Other minutes"
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that

```
[NSString localizedStringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%i minutes", nil), 5 ];
```

passes only *one argument* (the integer `5`) to the string formatting function,
but the format expands to

```
 %i %#@minutes@
```

which expects *two arguments*. So the first `%i` is
substituted by `5`, and the next `%#@minutes@` is substituted by something undefined.
One possible fix would be to use a "positional parameter":

```
 %i %1$#@minutes@
```

The `1$` part in the second format specifies that this should be filled from the 
*first* argument.

Alternatively, move the first `%i` format into the possible replacements.
Then the stringsdict file looks like this:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>%i minutes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@minutes@</string>
        <key>minutes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>d</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>%i One minute</string>
            <key>two</key>
            <string>%i Two minutes</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>%i Other minutes</string>
            <key>zero</key>
            <string>%i Zero minutes</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

But note that for the English language, plural rules are only supported for "zero" and "one", but not for "two", as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21095611/1187415.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I missed this detail and now I can pluralize my app correctly. Cheers!